# find a value in an XML file in Python without knowing the structure

Tags: python, xml

I have to get a specific value from different xml files with different structures (some simple, some more complicated). They all have this element `<CurrencyPair>XXXYYY</CurrencyPair>` in a different place.

I only need that value XXXYYY. Is there a way to get it regardless of the structure in Python?

Comment: Sure. Use an XML parser with [Xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) support (e.g., [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/)), and then you can search for `//CurrencyPair` to find that element regardless of its position in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`xml.dom.minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) for this task following way

```
import xml.dom.minidom
def getText(nodelist):
    rc = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
    return ''.join(rc)
document = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Parent id="top"><CurrencyPair>XXXYYY</CurrencyPair></Parent>'
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(document)
for cur_pair in dom.getElementsByTagName("CurrencyPair"):
    print(getText(cur_pair.childNodes))
```

gives output

```
XXXYYY
```

Note: getText is lifted verbatim from docs, use `parse` rather than `parseString` if you wish to process XML file rather than XML stored in str.